# Looking for the best 'search by car' extension

Tags: module, magento-1, search

I am new to Magento, currently putting together my store and moving away from Prestashop. I have seen many extensions which are able to facilitate a search part by car model function but I dont know which is best. Does anyone have experience of any extension and could offer advice?

I have quickly searched on the main extension website and found some that are able to set variables which can be searched from the front end.

What I would like is an extension that can be set to have the following options.

Model Make Year

then within each product these are defined so when a customer enters their car make, model and year it only shows the relevant products

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your question. However it's a bit too broad. Could you for example add the functionalities you are looking for and what the pros and cons are of the current extension(s) you have found

Comment: The problem I have with Amasty Product Finder, and all of the others, is that they are very basic. I run into situations where I have a brake pad that might fit front brake for one Motorcycle, but rear for another, or both for even another. Setting up attributes isn't really working either. I had looked at vehiclefits as it seemed to have the most promising features, but people did have problems with it. I would love someone to come up with all the bells and whistle that vehiclefits promises but actually work!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this https://amasty.com/product-parts-finder.html it is very good and support is awesome

This how it looks after customization

[image]

Comment: I can only recommend amasty.com as well, although I have not used this particular extension.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing broad about it. Actually there aren't, the problem is that they are for the most part unstable. The one we came across the most was, from memory, http://vehiclefits.com/download/magento, however people had bugs with the session handling. Whether they are now all solved not sure. We do it differently but it's not transferable so wouldn't help you, the website method doesn't work as Magento implodes on iteself with 10s of websites. You'll actually just have to test each one, but limit the amount of code and number of extensions, due to what you are trying to do the more unstable you make your implementation the more problems you will have, and pick a reliable high-grade host so you don't have architecture impacting your site such as poor session management.